# Prove that $Z(SL_n(F)) = SL_n(F) \cap Z(GL_n(F))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $F$ be any field and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $Z(SL_n(F)) = SL_n(F) \cap Z(GL_n(F))$.

**My Attempt**: We know that $SL_n(F) \trianglelefteq GL_n(F) $ and $Z(SL_n(F)) \trianglelefteq SL_n(F)$, so $Z(GL_n(F)) \subseteq Z(SL_n(F))$. Which implies $SL_n(F) \cap Z(GL_n(F)) \subseteq Z(SL_n(F))$.

**Facts\Definitions**:

$1) \det : GL_n(F) \rightarrow F^{\times} \\ 2) \, \ker \det = SL_n(F) = \{A \in GL_n(F) \mid \det(A) = 1 \} \\ 3) \, Z(GL_n(F)) = \{ aI_n \mid a \in F^{\times}\} \\ 4) \, \det(Z(GL_n(F))) = (F^{\times})^n $

I am not sure how we prove that  $Z(SL_n(F))\subseteq SL_n(F) \cap Z(GL_n(F))$. Is there any other way to prove this statement ?

Comment: It is not true that $Z(GL_n(F)) \subseteq Z(SL_n(F))$ (look at $\pmatrix{i & \\ & i}$). With $K$ the algebraic closure of $F$ then  $GL_n(F)\subset SL_n(F)K^*$ so if $A$ commutes with $SL_n(F)$ it commutes with $SL_n(F)K^*$ thus with $GL_n(F)$

Comment: Is it not true that if $A \leq B$ then $Z(B) \subseteq Z(A)$ @reuns ? since all the elements that commute with $B$ will also commute with $A$.

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with the term "Algebraic closure of a field".

Comment: Try with $H \le G$ two abelian groups

Comment: You have to show that, for any nonscalar matrix $g$ of ${\rm SL}_n(F)$, there is a matrix $h \in {\rm SL}_n(F)$ with $gh \ne hg$. To do that, it might help to replace $g$ by an appropriate similar matrix.